# Update QT Graphicview from other Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

i am at the moment really confused about threading in QT. I read so much different opinions which i can realize this.

I have a class (Computations) which do heavy computations and generate a lot of solution. When this class find a solution i call with help of

```
boost::function<void (Solution)> f;
```

a custom function. Which can be bind with

```
f = boost::bind( &MainWindow::FoundSolution, this,_1);
```

No i have my mainwindow in QT. There i call my class Computations with

```
Computations comp(f); 
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(comp,&Computations::DoSomethink);
```

So it compute while i can use the GUI and i get the response of new solutions to the FoundSolution function in my mainwindow. In this function I use QGraphicview to draw my solution. The Qgraphicsview is a member of my Mainwindow.

This works sometimes.

But i often get the following error

> Assert failure in QCOREApplication::SendEvent: " cannot send events to
>   objects owend by a different thread. Current thread 438bc40. Receiver
>   " (of type "Qgraphicsscene) was created in thread 15dcc00, file
>   kernel\qcoreapllication line 494

This mean i call my GUI application from a thread which is not the main and this is forbidden by QT. But with my boost bind i should be in my main thread or? And why it works sometimes ?

Do you know a better implementation for this? I am really new with QT and threads.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use signals and slots to the update so that it executes in the main window thread. What I mean is emit signals from the worker thread. Connect these signals to slots on your GUI objects that exist in the main thread.

Comment: the problem is that my worker thread is realized with QTConcurrent and there i dont have signals or? And my worker thread is without any Qt applications, so i cant realize Signals there. Because that i tried the way with boost bind and function.

Comment: You can use the Observer pattern to listen to the worker thread and emit the signals from the Observer, which will be a QObject in that case.

Comment: Has QT some Observe pattern function. Or it is possible that i use my Qobject and implement there my function for boost bind and emit then the signal. But then i have to call my Computation class inside the Qobject or?

Comment: You need to implement the Observer pattern yourself. This is not that hard to do. Google search for Observer Pattern you will get lots of hits. Although you may not find one that has a QObject as its base class. That should be very easy to add that..

Comment: The idea here is that you're working object is not able to emit the signal because it is not a QObject. All you need to do is to forward the call to another object that implements QObject and make that object emit the signal. Because you don't want your worker class to depend on another class that is tied to Qt, you use the Observer pattern to ensure that your worker class is completely independent of Qt.

Answer (score 2):

If you emit a signal from you worker thread that is connected to a slot of an object that lives in the ui thread, the slot will be executed in the ui thread.

So basically if you want to draw a new point in the QGraphicsView, send a signal from your worker thread passing in the coordinates of the new point to draw. The signal need to be connected to an object that lives in the ui thread. The slot will then handle drawing the new point in the QGraphicsView which will work since the slot is executed in the ui thread.

For more information see [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

Comment: And how come i do the same and the events are received... but in my case i output information into a TextBox. The text does not appear until the Thread is closed, but all text was received...so it updates at the end!. Is it related to this?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to use signals and slots. You can find some documentation, which is specific to your problem, here: [Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html), [Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-qobject.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 connect( &sender, SIGNAL(), &receiver, SLOT(), Qt::QueuedConnection)
```

The easier fix is to add Qt::QueuedConnection to the problematic slot connection call.